# C++ Printing a decimal given a numerator and denominator

Tags: c++, function, decimal, fractions

When I run this, I get a crazy number for my decimal.
Then, I'll run it again with the exact same numerator and denominator and it gives me something else different. I have no idea where the decimalValue is getting it's numberator and denominator that it's using. I want it to use the one that the user is forced to enter in the beginning of the program.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printLogo() {
    cout << "logo here" << endl;
}    

int AskFraction(int &numerator, int &denominator) {
    cout << "Enter numerator: ";
    cin >> numerator;
    cout << "Enter denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator;

    while (denominator == 0 || denominator < 0) {
        cout << "Denominator must be a number above zero." << endl;
        cout << "Enter denominator: ";
        cin >> denominator;
    }

    return numerator, denominator;
 }

float DecimalValue(float &decimalValue, int numerator, int denominator) {
if (denominator != 0 && denominator > 0) {
    decimalValue = numerator / denominator;
}

return decimalValue;
}

void PrintFraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << endl;
}

int main(int numerator, int denominator, float decimalValue) {

printLogo();

AskFraction(numerator, denominator);

DecimalValue(decimalValue, numerator, denominator);
cout << "The decimal value is: " << decimalValue << endl;

PrintFraction(numerator, denominator);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Please read the concept pass by value and pass by reference. 2. Cmd line args are expected to serve as input but not as variables taking input with in the program. 3. `return numerator, denominator;` hope compiler should have generated a warning.

Comment: In addition to what @Mahesh states, you are not assigning the return value of the `DecimalValue` function call to anything.

Comment: And moreover, the signature of the main function is not correct.

Comment: @Mahesh Okay I did the pass by reference stuff and changed my numerator, denominator, and decimalValue. I edited it in my question. But I'm still not getting the correct decimal at all - it gives 0 every time.

Comment: Both `numerator` and `denominator` are `int`, so, in C++, even if `decimalValue` is a `float`, you are performing an *integer* division (e.g. 2/3 -> 0). You haven't fix `return numerator, denominator;`, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: So all I have to do is change all the numerators and denominators to floats?

Comment: You can cast to `float` one of the terms, the other will be automatically converted by the compiler. You could even do something odd like `decimalValue = (numerator + 0.0)/ denominator;`. Besides, you are returning that value, so why are you also passing `decimalValue` by reference? `double decimalValue = DecimalValue(numerator, denominator);` makes more sense to me.

Comment: `main` doesn't take arguments like that.

Comment: One more thing, in order to avoid duplication of the lines `cout << "Enter denominator: ";` `cin >> denominator;`, you could you a `do-while` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a mix of notions. First, you pass variables by reference then try to return the value. Either use pass by reference or return the value of your result.

```
float DecimalValue(float &decimalValue, int numerator, int denominator) {
if (denominator != 0 && denominator > 0) {
    decimalValue = numerator / denominator;
}

return decimalValue;
}
```

This should be either:

```
void DecimalValue(float &decimalValue, int numerator, int denominator) {
if (denominator != 0 && denominator > 0) {
    decimalValue = numerator / denominator;
}    
}
```

Or

```
float DecimalValue(int numerator, int denominator) {
float decimalValue; //You should initialize this to a value. Decide this based on what you want to happen when the condition of the next if is false.
if (denominator != 0 && denominator > 0) {
    decimalValue = numerator / denominator;
}

return decimalValue;
}
```

Also, you have tried to return two values. In case you need to return multiple results, you need to use pass by reference. Like in:

```
int AskFraction(int &numerator, int &denominator) {
    cout << "Enter numerator: ";
    cin >> numerator;
    cout << "Enter denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator;

    while (denominator == 0 || denominator < 0) {
        cout << "Denominator must be a number above zero." << endl;
        cout << "Enter denominator: ";
        cin >> denominator;
    }

    return numerator, denominator;
 }
```

This should be:

```
void AskFraction(int &numerator, int &denominator) {
    cout << "Enter numerator: ";
    cin >> numerator;
    cout << "Enter denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator;

    while (denominator == 0 || denominator < 0) {
        cout << "Denominator must be a number above zero." << endl;
        cout << "Enter denominator: ";
        cin >> denominator;
    }    
 }
```

The final code after changing what I pointed above and also corrected main arguments is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printLogo() {
    cout << "logo here" << endl;
}    

void AskFraction(int &numerator, int &denominator) {
    cout << "Enter numerator: ";
    cin >> numerator;
    cout << "Enter denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator;

    while (denominator == 0 || denominator < 0) {
        cout << "Denominator must be a number above zero." << endl;
        cout << "Enter denominator: ";
        cin >> denominator;
    }    
 }

void DecimalValue(float &decimalValue, int numerator, int denominator) {
if (denominator != 0 && denominator > 0) {
    decimalValue = (float)numerator / denominator;
}

}

void PrintFraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << endl;
}

int main() {
int numerator, int denominator, float decimalValue
printLogo();

AskFraction(numerator, denominator);

DecimalValue(decimalValue, numerator, denominator);
cout << "The decimal value is: " << decimalValue << endl;

PrintFraction(numerator, denominator);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```